# How to find supremum and infimum of $(2014,2016]$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A=(2014,2016]$. Which of the following statements is/are true?

(a) $\sup A=2016$ and $\inf A=2014$

(b) $\sup A=2014$ and $\inf A=2016$

(c) $\sup A=2016$ and $\inf A$ does not exist

(d) $\sup A$ does not exist and $\inf A=2014$

(e) Both $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ do not exist.

**My try**

Since there is no possible least number inf does not exist and $\sup(A)=2016$.
Is my argument correct?

Comment: You are not correct that there is no infimum. The infimum is not the smallest number of a set. It is the greatest lower bound for a set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing between infimum and minimum. Infimum is the largest lower bound of the set. So the definition doesn't say the infimum must belong to the set itself. If it does belong to the set then it is called minimum. So what is the greatest lower bound of your set? Obviously it is $2014$. Why? First of all it is a lower bound. And it is easy to see that any bigger number than $2014$ is already not a lower bound of $A$.

Comment: This clarifies my doubts. So here Maximum and Supremum are Both 2016. But only infimum is 2014 right?

Comment: Yes. In general, if a maximum exists then it is equal to the supremum. If minimum exists then it is equal to the infimum. So in your example the supremum is $2016$ and it is also a maximum. $2014$ is the infimum but it is not a minimum. The set has no minimum.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it addressed the OP's lack of argument for why $\operatorname{sup}(A)=2016$.

Answer (score 2):

> "Since there is no possible least number inf does not exist"

You're thinking of the *minimum* there, not the *infimum*; the infimum is the greatest lower bound of the set.

Also, you have presented no argument as to why $\operatorname{sup}(A)=2016$.

Answer (score 1):

For a *bounded* set like the interval $A$ here, supremum and infimum *always* exist and are equal to the larger and smaller numbers defining the interval's endpoints respectively, so the answer must be A, not C.